# Why is the outside container scrolling even though the overflow is in the inside container?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to make a basic draggable div with a title bar and some content.

However, I have come across a problem where if there is too much content and scrolling is introduced, both the title bar and content will scroll even though only the content is overflowing.

After inspecting it, it seems as if the entire `.draggable` element is scrolling even though the overflow is only in `.content`. I've tried removing the `overflow: auto` from `.draggable`, but then the content doesn't scroll at all and it goes out of the window.

I am not sure why this is happening at all, and I've tried a lot of things with none of the working.

### Before Scrolling

Notice the title bar on top of both of the windows.

[image: before scrolling]

### After scrolling

After scrolling, the title bar goes along with the content even though it is in a seperate div.

[image: after scrolling]

Here is the JSFiddle link for more in-depth look.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dq04x6uv/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to scroll the .content and let the .title always on top try this.

```
.draggable {
    //...rest of code
    overflow: hidden;
}

.draggable > .content {
    height: 100%;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
```